# Details about Symbolize

Tags: custom-notation

When I'm using Symbolize function, there are some details that I'm not sure. For example:

```
<< Notation`
Symbolize[Subscript[q, 1],Subscript[q, 2]];(*I want to declare two symbols with subscript*)
```

1. Can I type the name "Symbolize[...]" instead of using the Notation Palette？It seems there is a little distinction,  Notation Palette has a colored region:

   [image]
2. Does "Symbolize" support multiple inputs, such as the above example?
    What if i want to declare as many as 100 variables with subscript?

I want to do differentiation on q1.

```
Subscript[q, 1] /:D[Subscript[q, 1], t, NonConstants -> {Subscript[q, 1]}] := 
Subscript[dq, 1];
D[Subscript[q, 1]^2, t]
```

I expect to get 2*q1*dq1, but Mathematica gives 0. Why is that?

Comment: extract from the notation tutorial : "When defining your own notations it is critically important to use the notation templates."

Comment: user5463 I see that you have not [Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/158428) answers to any of your questions.  Please consider going through your questions and Accepting some answers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot simply type `Symbolize[...]` which you should probably know from an error message you should be getting. For example what you have in your question gives:

```
Symbolize[Subscript[q, 1],Subscript[q, 2]]
```

[image]

To see why you get this message you can use show expression to see what is being pasted via the palette:

[image]

From this we can see that `Symbolize` makes use of `TemplateBox`es so the easiest way to get the correct coding is to use the palette.

For the other part of your question you probably should have found that you got an error when you entered a sequence of multiple inputs, so the answer is, no, it does not support multiple inputs. The objective is to take an expression and have it treated as a symbol.

Note that you can use patterns so rather than

```
Symbolize[Subscript[q, 1],Subscript[q, 2]];
```

which will cause an error, you can enter

```
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["q", "_"]]]
```

...which unfortunately doesn't display ideally in this formatting when you cut and paste so here is the screen grab

[image]

The first pic shows me entering `q` and a subscript box then in the next pic I have entered an underscore in the subscript box. So now any `q` with a subscript (`Subscript[q, 1]` and `Subscript[q, 2]` etc.) are treated as symbols.

---

**Edit #1**

If you want to symbolize all subscripts then use this pattern:

```
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]]]
```

In the screen grab below you can see that changed interpretation once all subscripts are treated as symbols:

[image]

---

**...ok final edit**

> I expect to get 2*q1*dq1, but Mathematica gives 0. Why is that?

[image]

If you get something different I assume it is a typing error or a problem with your version on your platform. For this answer I have been using 8.0.4 on mac 10.6.8

---

**[This really is the final edit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Never_Say_Never_Again)**

[image]

Comment: Sorry, i cannot state the problem clearly in the comment window, so i move it to my question.

Comment: As I said in an earlier comment, that is where you should be providing the information from the outset.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But after symbolizing q1, how can i clear it? Subscript[q, 1] =. doesn't work.

Comment: Read the documentation for the `Notations` package and then ask your question if you continue to have problems. Methods to clear notations and remove symbolize are discussed in the docs.

Comment: I tried this: RemoveSymbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]]]  doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have a symbol that consists of subscript with two empty strings? Sorry but this really is a case for reading the docs.

Comment: Would you please take a look at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136013/creating-a-list-of-symbolized-indexed-variables). Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. I have a question about the usage of these Symbols. Assume I run `Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["q", "_"]]]`, but then I want to generate a list of `{q_1, q_2, ..., q_k}` by running a Map over the list _Range[k]_. However if I type `q_i`, the `i` is treated as a symbol not a variable... How do I generate a list `{q_1, ... q_k}`?