# Using Greek letters with subscripts as symbols

Tags: symbols

I'd like to use `Subscript[ϕ, 1]` as a function name:

```
Subscript[ϕ, 1][x_] = C1 + C2*x + C3*Exp[α*x] + C4*Exp[-α*x]
```

But as I use

```
?Subscript[ϕ, 1]
```

I get the error meassage

```
Information::ssym: Subscript[ϕ, 1] is not a symbol or a valid string pattern. >>
```

How can I define `Subscript[ϕ, 1]` as a symbol so that I get an output?

Comment: Related: [(373)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/373/121)

Answer (score 3):

Best to use the `Notations` package and the function `Symbolize` which you will find discussed [elsewhere on this site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19759/details-about-symbolize/19760#19760) (and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20195/solve-with-v9-issues-with-subscript-overscript-superscript-etc/20208#20208)).

[image]

Note that I am using screen grabs rather than cut and paste because cut and paste is rather screwy for symbolized subscripts.

Comment: Okay, it seems the pseudo-Symbol behavior was not extended to `Information` in Version 7.  I'm getting rid of my comments above.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard FWIW I am using V8 this evening.

Answer (score 0):

Please read:  [Can we use letter with a subscript as a variable in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1004/121)

A few points:

**1:** You probably want to use `SetDelayed` rather than `Set`:  `Subscript[ϕ, 1][x_] := . . .`

**2:** The definition *is* made but it is attached to `Subscript`:

```
Subscript[ϕ, 1][x_] := C1 + C2*x + C3*Exp[α*x] + C4*Exp[-α*x]

?? Subscript
```

> ```
> Attributes[Subscript] = {NHoldRest}
>
> Subscript[ϕ, 1][x_] := C1 + C2 x + C3 Exp[α x] + C4 Exp[-α x]
> ```

**3:** The definition works as expected:

```
Subscript[ϕ, 1][7]
```

> ```
> C1 + 7 C2 + C4 E^(-7 α) + C3 E^(7 α)
> ```

**4:** If you were not also using a [`SubValues` pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7999/121) you could use `TagSet`/`TagSetDelayed` to attach the definition to the Symbol `ϕ`:

```
ϕ /: Subscript[ϕ, 2] := "stuff"

? ϕ
```

> ```
> ϕ /: Subscript[ϕ, 2] := stuff
> ```