# About Symbolize and Variables

Tags: symbolic, variable-definitions, symbols

I do believe this sort of similar questions had been asked many times, so I have read a LOT. For example [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19759/details-about-symbolize) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13741/how-to-create-symbol-whose-name-has-subscript) as well as many other related posts.

But a glance at what my main question is this:

```
Needs["Notation`"]

Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["x", "_"]]]
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["y", "_"]]]
var1 = Table[ToExpression["Subscript[x, " <> ToString[i] <> "]"], {i, 10}]
var2 = Table[ToExpression["Subscript[y, " <> ToString[i] <> "]"], {i, 10}]

1/(1 + Exp[var1 + var2])
(* Does not work *)
Variables[%]

1/(1 + Exp[var1 + var2])
(* Does work *)
Variables[Level[%,4]]
```

Now the real challenge is: I need expression for TWO sets of variables (symbols) $p_{jc}$ and $\phi_{jc}$, like this
$$
p_{jc}
=
\frac{1}{1+\exp{(-\mu_p-\tau_{pj}-\eta_{pc}})}
$$
and
$$
\phi_{jc}
=
\frac{1}{1+\exp{(-\mu_\phi-\tau_{\phi j}-\eta_{\phi c}})}
$$
for different $j$s and $c$s.

Ideally,  I want to define variables like $\mu_{\phi},\mu_p,\tau_{pj}$, ect. They need to be treated like a variable by the function `Variables`, not when I `Level` out the expression.

I coded the whole thing in Maple with out any problem, but in Mathematica, this seen to be very difficult to do so. The similar command for `Variables` in Maple is [`indets`](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=indets).

I now wonder:

1 - Is that possible to define things like $\mu_{\phi},\tau_{\phi j},\eta_{\phi c}$. How?

2 - When I use these symbols, are they going to be recognized without any problem by `Variables`?

This is particularly important because I write functions that take $j$ and $c$ to create the variables above, then a complicated expression, involving exponential. I want to determine the "number of parameters".

3 - A bit vague, but more to do. I will use these symbols to create function, and do optimizations, and replace `/.` using rules. Would that have difficulties?
See the [PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5073hyxaiporp6x/toy_example.pdf?dl=0) . Page 1, `sskappa(ss,kappa);` transforms expression (1) to expression (4) using rules (3).

4 - Just as a note to the `Symbolize` command, why does `Variables` do not treat the Symbolized variables as variables? (get me {} as shown above in the code)

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5073hyxaiporp6x/toy_example.pdf?dl=0) is a PDF file, produced by Maple, on briefly what I am trying to get in Mathematica. Don't worry to much about the expression "kappa", but what I can do with "kappa", for example, using Maple command `indets`.

Any advise on how to approach this would be appreciated!

Comment: I believe your solution modified as: Variables[Level[%, -1]] would work for you in many more cases.

Comment: @BryggaTe Yes, that is essentially what I proposed [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30048/121).  The `{-1}`, meaning *only* expressions at the deepest level rather than expressions at all levels may be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moment leaving aside the wisdom of using Subscripts as Symbols in *Mathematica* it would appear that your immediate problem has nothing to do with `Subscript` at all but rather the behavior of [`Variables`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Variables.html).

Recall its definition:

> `Variables[poly]` gives a list of all independent variables in a polynomial.

And observe that even when using true Symbols you do not get the result you desire:

```
var1 = Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, 10}];
var2 = Table[Symbol["y" <> ToString[i]], {i, 10}];

expr = 1/(1 + Exp[var1 + var2]);

Variables[expr]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

Comment: I see. `Variables` was suggested to me, as a similar command to the Maple `indets`. So what's the best approach to this ? Can Mathematica determine all variables (or symbols) that in an expression need to be determined? I really do hope there is a way out.

Comment: @Chen Since I am not familiar with `indets` I don't know what you are attempting to implement and where it is failing.  What is wrong with using `Level`?  That was the proposed solution to this (I think) related question: [(30038)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30038/121)

Comment: What if I do this? `var2 = Table[Symbol["y" <> ToString[i]], {i, 10}]; Variables[Level[%*Exp[%]^%, -1]]`.  This would fail. My point is, Using `Level` will have to change, it depends on the `complicated structure` of the `expr`. Maybe a fixed `level` works for a particular structure, but it just seem wasted. As a comparison, the Maple `indets` command is more "straightforward" in this case. (I have also missed understood what `Variables` does until you mentioned its definition, but it's not very relevant to the point I am trying to make, I think.)

Comment: @Chen Please post a new Question about a *Mathematica* equivalent for Maple `indets`, along with examples where `Variables` (with or without `Level`) fails to give the desired result.

Comment: OK! I will do so in a minute.

Comment: @Chen Make sure you link [(30038)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30038/121) in your question so that people know you are aware of it and don't close your question as a duplicate.  (Also make sure that your examples clearly show the proposed method there failing.)