# Creating a List of Symbolized Indexed Variables

Tags: variable, custom-notation

I am trying to creat a list of indexed variables (symbols) using the `Notation` package and `Symbolize` command.

As an example, suppose that I want to a creat a list of variables like ${x_1,...,x_{20}}$ but I want all of them to be **symbols**. How can I creat a list of symbolized indexed variables?

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify which part you find unexpected, so we can provide better answers. Perhaps we could start from here: `Information` (i.e. `??`) is `HoldAll` so it won't evaluate `Var[[1]]` to its contents. You could try `Information[Evaluate[Var[[1]]]` instead. More in general, however, when you assign values to subscripted variables, the value is actually associated with the `Subscript` function, and not with the variable.

Comment: See perhaps [(1005)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1005/27951), [(373)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/373/27951).

Comment: @MarcoB: Ah! So my first question is answered!? :) What about the second one. :)

Comment: @MarcoB: Please note that if one uses the `Symbolize` command then there will be no problem for assigning. :)

Comment: I am not familiar enough with the Notation package to comment on those points. In general, though, I would suggest that you look into [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html), or simply use e.g. `x[1, 3]` instead of $x_{1,3}$. See e.g. [(114632)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114632/27951) and links, and search this site for "alternatives to Subscript".

Comment: @MarcoB: Thanks for the guides. I edited the first question. would you please take a look at it.

Answer (score 4):

I used to do this with `` Notation`Symbolize ``, but it had some shortcomings like, if you save expressions on disk and later load into another notebook, then symbolization is not preserved automatically, and you end up with lots of names with `\[UnderBracket]` in them. Even more important, you cannot create a list of symbolized indexed variables by just using `Table[Subscript[x, j], {j, 10}]`. I found a different approach, and so far it serves my needs pretty well.

*Mathematica* allows many Unicode characters in symbol names, including subscript digits `₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉`. So, I create indexed variables using these digits in symbol names, but because they are not easy to enter and they look in notebooks slightly different than regular subscripts, I format them as regular subscripted expressions using `MakeBoxes`, and use `Subscript` to create them on demand from regular subscripts. When I save expressions containing symbols with subscripts on disk, in the worst case they will be loaded as regular symbols with Unicode subscript digits in their names (e.g. `x₁₂`) that is still pretty readable.

The following code will automatically symbolize all subscripted symbols in `` Global`‍ `` context:

```
With[{regular = CharacterRange["0", "9"], 
   subscripts = CharacterRange[8320, 8329]}, (* ₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉ *)

  With[{pat = Alternatives[subscripts], 
    toSub = Thread[regular -> subscripts], 
    fromSub = Thread[subscripts -> regular]},

   $NewSymbol = Function[{name, ctx},
     If[ctx === "Global`" && StringEndsQ[name, pat],
      With[{len = StringPosition[name, pat][[1, 1]] - 1},
       With[{s = StringTake[name, len],
             index = StringReplace[StringDrop[name, len], fromSub]},
        With[{ex = MakeExpression["Global`" <> name, StandardForm]},
         ReleaseHold[Hold[
           MakeBoxes[ex, StandardForm] := 
             InterpretationBox[SubscriptBox[s, index], ex, 
               Editable -> True, AutoDelete -> True]]
                 /. HoldComplete[h_] :> h]]]]]];

   SetAttributes[Subscript, HoldFirst];
   Subscript[s_Symbol /; Context[Unevaluated[s]] === "Global`", j_Integer /; j >= 0] :=
     ToExpression["Global`" <> SymbolName[Unevaluated[s]]
       <> StringReplace[ToString[j], toSub]]]];
```

Please feel free to criticize or propose improvements.

Comment: (+1) Thanks Vladimir. :)

Comment: Nice alternative. I've been using NotationSymbolize, and a way to programmatically generate a list of pretty, symbolized, subscripted variables (where `Table[Subscript[x, j], {j, 10}]` doesn't work) is: `X = ToExpression[SubscriptBox["x", ToString[#]]]&/@Range[10]` (see Mr.Wizard's answer to my question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224265/symbolized-subscripted-variable-doesnt-look-pretty)).

One limitation of your approach: Functions with subscripted arguments don't seem to work.

Also, how do you "undo" the approach above? (e.g. just `Clear["Global`*"]`?)

Comment: @Sterling These are valid points. But usually they do not bother me much in my scenarios. To use a subscripted variable as an ad hoc function parameter I either pre-evaluate the subscripted variable and paste it where needed, or use input aliases for subscript digits: ```Scan[Notation`AddInputAlias, {"0" -> ParsedBoxWrapper["\:2080"], …}]```. In most cases I generate those definitions by a program and create subscripted symbols and their formatting rules explicitly.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov, thank you. What do you mean by pre-evaluate the subscripted variables? Before when I tried with your approach, I think using it as a function argument still produced an error even if I had evaluated the subscripted variables manually. I wasn't familiar with input aliases before, and that seems like a pretty reasonable approach. If I end up needing to save variables to disk and reload them or run into other limitations with the Symbolize package, I'll keep this approach in mind. Hopefully this is some useful discussion for others to decide as well.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you don't need to - you can use a pattern (e.g `Subscript[x,_]`) inside a `Symbolize` box. This will generate the symbols as required.

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the attention. :) Yes this would also work.

Comment: @H.R. if you're indexing by ints greater than 0 note that the pattern that is most protective is `_Integer?Positive`.

Comment: @MB1965: That is a nice point. It will be good if you add some nice patterns for different indexing to your answer too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is as simple way to create a list of symbolized variables $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{20}$ as follows

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Needs["Notation`"]

Do[Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["x", ToString[i]]]], {i, 1,
   20}]

x = 1
(*1*)

Subscript[x, 1]
(*x_1*)
```

Comment: It's worth keeping in mind that this is just front-end magic. If you used ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitionsLocal`` on `Symbolize` you find it just constructs a bunch of symbols looking like `x\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]i` and then coerces the box representations with `MakeExpression` and `MakeBoxes`. It'll work for most simple usages, but it absolutely requires the front end and the `Symbolize` call to work. Another point of interest: if you want to get the information on such symbols all one needs to use is `?? "x\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]*"`.

Comment: @MB1965: Thanks for the attention. What we see is clearly the front end notation so I find it useful to make use of these things for better readability of the code. :) Also getting information is not that much painful as you say. The keyboard entry is simply "? x crtl+_ 1". :)

Comment: yes, but if you want the definitions for *all* of the subscripted symbols you require that (I believe). `Information` takes a placeholder form with `"*"` to spit out all matching forms but this has to be a string. Similarly with `Clear` or `Remove`.