# Using Subscripted Notation without Introducing new identifier

Tags: variable-definitions, subscript, notation

I would like to use subscripted notation such as $\sigma_x$ as identifiers for use as variables.  In this example I am using the Pauli Matrices so that I would use notation such as:
$$
\sigma_x = \{\{0,1\},\{1,0\}\}
$$
However, when defining the expression, two variables or identifiers are defined in my current context.  Using the Names function for the context I would find that the two identifiers $\sigma$ and $x$ are both individually defined but the identifier symbol $\sigma_x$ is not defined.

How do I prevent the individual definition of the $\sigma$ and $x$ and force the definition of the ONE subscripted identifier $\sigma_x$?

Comment: [related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/374/5467)

Comment: Have a read through these: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29043/using-greek-letters-with-subscripts-as-symbols/29046#29046 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33672/preventing-superscript-from-being-interpreted-as-power-when-using-ctrl-shortcu/33689#33689 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19759/details-about-symbolize/19760#19760 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20195/solve-with-v9-issues-with-subscript-overscript-superscript-etc/20208#20208

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [x] instead of subscript-x:

```
Clear[σ, x];
σ[x] := {{0,1},{1,0}};
{σ, x, σ[x]}
```

It's not as elegant as a subscript, but it works. Just be sure not to define 'x' elsewhere!