# How to treat Subscript objects as constants when using D

Tags: custom-notation, subscript

I want to define a constant vector {$k_x , k_y , k_z$}.
The problem is that Mathematica gives me 
D[$k_x$,x]$=k_1$. I want this to be zero, because $k_x$ is a constant.

Clearly D[$k_x$,x]$=k_1$ makes sense since $k_x=$Subscript[k,x] but it is still quite annoying because it is contrary to standard notation.

How to tell Mathematica that Subscript[k,x] is just a variable name (instead of two variables, k and x, inside the function Subscript)?

Comment: Well, there are ways of 'overloading' standard behavior but it is not a recommended practice. See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1005/34848) for some ideas.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19759/details-about-symbolize/19760#19760

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29043/using-greek-letters-with-subscripts-as-symbols/29046#29046

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20195/solve-with-v9-issues-with-subscript-overscript-superscript-etc/20208#20208

Comment: Though if you are new with Mathematica perhaps you should avoid doing that in the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to not use symbols inside of your subscripts:

```
D[Subscript["k", "x"], x]
```

> 0

In [`StandardForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm), they look the same:

```
{Subscript[k, x], Subscript["k", "x"]}
```

[image]

**Addendum**

If you must use symbols instead of strings, then you can change a system option so that [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript) objects are not differentiable:

```
SetSystemOptions[
    "DifferentiationOptions" -> "ExcludedFunctions" -> DeleteDuplicates @ Append[
        OptionValue[SystemOptions[], "DifferentiationOptions"->"ExcludedFunctions"],
        Subscript
    ]
];
```

Then:

```
D[Subscript[k, x], x] //InputForm
```

> D[Subscript[k, x], x]

Mathematica knows there's an `x` inside the subscript, so it thinks the result isn't 0, but the "ExcludedFunctions" setting means Mathematica doesn't know what to do with the subscript. So, we need to define an [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues):

```
D[_Subscript, __] ^:= 0
```

Now:

```
D[Subscript[k, x], x]
```

> 0