# How to stop Mathematica from deriving index?

Tags: subscript

If I have two variables $k, k_x$ with $k_x\neq f(k)$, 
it is obvious that
$$\frac{\partial k_x}{\partial k}=0$$
In Mathematica, I need the `Subscript[]` function to implement is derivative in an aesthetic way:

[image]

This leads to the issue seen above. How to get rid of Mathematica's interpretation of the `Subscript[]` function - considering it to be a mathematical function that has to be derived too but as a "stylistic device"?

PS: The desired solution should be $=0$.

Comment: TIP: never use `Subscript`s.

Comment: Haha, thanks. But I want to use TeXForm for LaTeX output and therefore, It would be very comfortable to have it already in the right style/form. Subscripts are well translated into LaTeX subscripts. However, can you help me with that?

Comment: duplicate? : [How to treat Subscript objects as constants when using D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/183080/125)

Comment: @Kutsubato Do all your calculations without subscripts, and substitute them back only at the very end, when exporting them to latex.

Comment: @kglr You are right - it covers big parts of my question - but actually, I have not found that solution. Sorry, I am very new to Mathematica.

Comment: I wouldn't say never use `Subscript` ... but if you do use `Subscript[a,b]` then do not use `a` and `b` separately. This will eventually lead to problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all contributions. According to @Roman, the use of `Format` is possible as well. I did it like this and it worked:

```
Format[cv] := Subscript[c, v]; 
Format[lv] := Subscript[l, v];
Format[Jz] := Subscript[J, z];
Format[beta] := \[Beta];
Format[psidot] := OverDot[\[Psi]];
```

This is my preamble - so it comes right before all other code. In the end, after I have applied calculations to the variables inside the `Format` function, I can use `TeXForm` to turn them into LaTeX code and in this code, my format options are already applied.

Answer (score 7):

This can be solved by applying custom formatting to `kx` rather than using `Subscript`:

```
kx /: MakeBoxes[kx, TraditionalForm | StandardForm] := SubscriptBox["k", "x"];
```

Then `kx` will be output as $k_x$, and the derivative will be correct:

```
D[kx, k]
```

> 0

Would highly recommend looking at `TagSet` (`/:`) and `MakeBoxes` in the documentation for further information.

Due to the `TraditionalForm` used in the `MakeBoxes` pattern, this will also work with `TeXForm`:

```
TeXForm[kx]
```

> k_x

@Roman also suggested `Format` as an alternative, so to provide some clarification there:

```
Format[kx] := Subscript[k, x];
```

By assigning `Format[_]`, the output format of `_` can be changed. It's a bit less excessively low-level, as Roman comments. In my own personal experience with *Mathematica*, it's almost a bit less intuitive, but your mileage will vary. This also works properly with `TeXForm`.

Regarding `OverDot`, that is also possible in these cases. For example, with `v`:

```
Format[v] := OverDot[v];
```

Or:

```
v /: MakeBoxes[v, TraditionalForm | StandardForm] := OverscriptBox["v", "."];
```

Comment: Thank you. That should work for pretty much all cases!

Comment: Is there an equivalent for the OverDot function?

Comment: I find assigning values to `Format` a bit less low-level than tag-setting `MakeBoxes`.

Comment: @Roman TRUE! I looked it up and it works for me as well. Furthermore, it covers solutions for my problem with other operators like `OverDot`. Thanks to all of you.

Comment: The simple explanation makes it way more accessible now! Thank you for the great micro tutorial. I’m wondering how this relates to @Roman’s suggestion of using format, can you clarify this possible? I’ll go learn and read myself, too, of course :)

Comment: @Roman Fair. I'm just personally more familiar with the super low-level way of doing things, so thanks for the note. @Kutsubato I included an implementation for `OverDot` with `MakeBoxes` as well. `MakeBoxes` is quite powerful, but definitely somewhat trickier to use. `Format` should handle 99% of normal formatting needs, for sure.

Comment: Okay thank you! I will have a look at it.